# How does the automatic Ansible documentation work?

Tags: python, documentation, ansible, yaml, python-sphinx

So this is my situation:
I am writing Ansible playbooks and roles in a huge project directory. Currently my documentation is stored in .md files. But I want to use Ansible's documentation mechanism, so I looked into the sphinx documentation system. It seems pretty neat to me, so I installed it and got into the mechanisms.

But what I cant figure out: How does Ansible include the documentation that is located in the python modules into the sphinx documentation?
I am sorry to be not able to be more specific, but currently I am just scratching the surface I assume.

So here is what I want to achieve:

- I have the typical `roles` directory
- In it there are several roles
- The files are mainly .yaml or .yml files
- I at least want to include documentation from one file within these role directories
- Ideally I want to pull documentation from several files within the directory

If too much is unclear please tell me and I will try to improve the question as I can't figure out for hours how to achieve this or even how to ask precisely.

**Thanks in advance for every comment and answer!**

Answer (score 4):

Auto doc is only for Ansible modules, not playbooks.
If you want to document your playbooks, you are on your own.
There is a small project on github: [ansible-docgen](https://github.com/starboarder2001/ansible-docgen) – it fetches a list of tasks into MD files and adds a couple of headers.
You can achive comparable result by calling `ansible-playbook --list-tasks myplaybook.yml`

In my personal opinion, reading playbooks with comments is very convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much Konstantin! You gave me some important hints I will look into. But are you capable of explaining the mechanism of the documentation process itself? That would really answer my question, so everybody who stumbles over this gets a good answer. Thanks!